# if $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ in $X$, then $Tx_n \rightharpoonup Tx$ in $Y$ , for $T \in B(X, Y )$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, solution-verification, weak-convergence

Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces and $T \in B(X, Y )$ be linear operator. Show that if $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ in $X$, then $Tx_n \rightharpoonup Tx$ in $Y$ .

**My attempt**

since $T \in B(X, Y )$, $\|T\| < \infty$ , given that $x_n \rightharpoonup x$, choose $N$ such that $\|\langle x_n,z\rangle-\langle x,z\rangle\| \le \frac{\epsilon}{\|T\|} , \ \forall n>N , \forall z\in 
 X. \ \ \ $ Then;

\begin{align}
\|\langle Tx_n,z\rangle-\langle Tx,z\rangle\| 
& = \|\langle T(x_n-x),z\rangle\|\\
& \le \|T\|\|\langle (x_n-x),z\rangle\| \\
& = \|T\|\|\langle x_n,z\rangle-\langle x,z\rangle\| \\
& \le \|T\|\frac{\epsilon}{\|T\|} = \epsilon  , \ \ \forall z \in X
\end{align}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems with what you wrote:

- You seem to be treating $X$ as a Hilbert space, and assuming that $Y=X$. In a general Banach space there is no inner product nor Riesz Representation Theorem.
- You cannot choose $N$ uniformly on $z$, as you wrote.
- You write norms when applied to numbers, which is not necessarily wrong (the absolute value in $\mathbb C$ is actually a norm) but it's weird.
- Your first estimate makes no sense, even in a Hilbert space.

How to do the exercise:

In a Banach space, that $x_n\to x$ weakly means that (the numbers) $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ for all $f\in X^*$.  The exercise is then trivial, since given $T\in B(X,Y)$ and $g\in Y^*$, then $g\circ T\in X^*$. Then $g(Tx_n)\to g(Tx_n)$ by hypothesis.

Comment: so if I assume the Hilbert spaces and change as the following would it make sense? (I did not get your 4th point.)
$\forall z\in X$ choose $N$ such that $|\langle x_n,z\rangle-\langle x,z\rangle| \le \frac{\epsilon}{\|T\|} , \ \forall n>N , . \ \ \ $ Then;  $\forall z \in X$

\begin{align}
|\langle Tx_n,z\rangle-\langle Tx,z\rangle| 
& = |\langle T(x_n-x),z\rangle|\\
& \le \|T\||\langle (x_n-x),z\rangle| \\
& = \|T\||\langle x_n,z\rangle-\langle x,z\rangle| \\
& \le \|T\|\frac{\epsilon}{\|T\|} = \epsilon 
\end{align}

Comment: No. My 4th point says that the inequality $|\langle Tx,z\rangle|\leq \|T\|\,|\langle x,z\rangle|$ is wrong.

Comment: For instance try $$T=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ x=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\end{bmatrix},\ \ z=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\end{bmatrix}. $$

Comment: I do not understand you in this statement "Then $g(Tx_n)\to g(Tx_n)$ by hypothesis. " the hypothesis was on $x_{n}$ and $x$ not $Tx_{n}$ and $Tx$, could you please explain this?

Comment: Call $g\circ T$ as $h$, and write $h(x_n)\to h(x)$.