# Prove that $T$ is bounded iff $x_{n} \rightharpoonup x \quad \Rightarrow \quad Tx_{n} \rightharpoonup Tx.$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, reflexive-space

Could any one help me in proving this question please:

Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space and $T: X \rightarrow X$ a linear operator. Prove that $T$ is bounded iff $$x_{n} \rightharpoonup x \quad \Rightarrow \quad Tx_{n} \rightharpoonup Tx.$$

I found this question here:

[if $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ in $X$, then $Tx_n \rightharpoonup Tx$ in $Y$ , for $T \in B(X, Y )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3603647/if-x-n-rightharpoonup-x-in-x-then-tx-n-rightharpoonup-tx-in-y-for)

But I do not understand if this is an answer for the question or no, I got confused from the information there, could anyone clarify what is written for me please?

Comment: That question proves 'only if' and you need to show 'if' here

Comment: @user58955 Where am I going to use the reflexivity of $X$?

Comment: You are right. I don't think you need reflexivity of $X$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3603666/22857) you mention shows your implication $\implies$.

Reflexivity of $X$ is not needed (but I have left below an argument that uses it). The key observation is that any weakly convergent sequence (not net!) is bounded. This follows from the [Uniform Boundedness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle): for each $f\in Y^*$, the sequence (of numbers) $\{f(Tx_n)\}$ is bounded; that is, $$\sup\{|f(Tx_n)|:\ n\}<\infty$$ for each $f\in Y^*$. Using $\{\widehat{Tx_n}\}\subset Y^{**}$ as the family $F$ in the UBP, we get that
$$
\sup\{\|Tx_n\|:\ n\}=\sup\{|f(Tx_n)|:\ n\in\mathbb N,\ \|f\|=1\}<\infty
$$
Now, if $T$ were unbounded, there would exist a sequence $x_n$ such that $x_n\to0$ and $\|Tx_x\|>n$. This would give a sequence with $x_n\rightharpoonup0$ such that $Tx_n$ does not converge weakly.

---

**Using reflexivity of $X$:**

We want to show that $T$ is continuous: that is, if $x_n\to x$, then $Tx_n\to Tx$. Because of linearity, it is enough to show that $x_n\to0$ implies $Tx_n\to0$. So suppose that $x_n\to0$. Then of course $x_n\rightharpoonup0$, which by hypothesis implies that $Tx_n\rightharpoonup0$. Because [every weakly convergence sequence is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/825790/22857), the sequence $\{Tx_n\}$ is bounded. Because $X$ is reflexive, closed balls are weakly compact. So there exists a convergent subsequence $\{Tx_{n_k}\}$. Say $Tx_{n_k}\to y$. Since strong convergence implies weak convergence, $y=0$. Now we can apply this last reasoning to every subsequence of $\{Tx_n\}$: that is, [any subsequence of $\{Tx_n\}$ has a subsequence that converges to $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70411/22857): so $Tx_n\to0$. Thus $T$ is continuous, so bounded.

Comment: I am not sure if reflexivity of $X$ is necessary here. Do you have a counterexample?

How about the following argument? If $T$ is not bounded, then there exists $\{x_n\}$ such that $x_n\to 0$ while $\|Tx_n\|\geq n$. Now, since $x_n\rightharpoonup 0$, we know from the assumption that $Tx_n \rightharpoonup 0$. But this means that $\|Tx_n\|$ is bounded, so we have a contradiction?

Comment: I think the statement should hold in general for $T:X\to Y$ for Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ without any reflexivity assumption.

Comment: You are right. I have edited the answer.

Comment: The reverse implication is a simple consequence of the closed-graph theorem.

Comment: In the reverse direction proof: I do not understand this sentence: "Because of linearity, it is enough to show that $x_n\to0$ implies $Tx_n\to0$." Could you clarify it please?

Comment: $x_n\to x\ \iff\ (x_n-x)\to0$. And $Tx_n\to Tx\ \iff\ T(x_n-x)\to0$.

Comment: And then you rename $(x_{n} - x)$ by another name or what ? as you build up a new sequence.

Comment: Yes, I rename it as $x_n$.

Comment: Do you have a proof for this "Because $X$ is reflexive, closed balls are weakly compact"?

Comment: I have a proof to this: " If $X$ is a reflexive Banach space then its closed unit ball is weakly sequentially compact." So I need $X$ to be complete not just normed space.

Comment: Do you have a proof for that $X$ is complete?

Comment: Yes; duals are always complete.

Comment: Where is the dual here sorry I can not see?

Comment: Do you know what "reflexive" means?

Comment: yess "A normed space $X$ is reflexive if the natural embedding $J: X \rightarrow X^{**}$ is surjective."

Comment: Do you mean that it is isometric isomorphic to the double dual?

Comment: Do you have a proof for that the duals are complete?

Comment: Yes, the double dual is a dual.

Comment: what about my last comment?

Comment: LMGTFY: https://www.google.com/search?q=dual+space+is+complete&oq=dual+space+is&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.9750j0j7&client=tablet-android-samsung-nf-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Perfect! +1 … it helped me a lot thank you!

Comment: Also how can I change my closed unit ball to your general balls? as I only took the statement for unit balls?

Comment: Do you mean in the line before last "to every subseqence $\{Tx_{n}\}$?

Comment: why the weak limit is the same as the strong limit for the same sequence?

Comment: "Now, if 
 were unbounded, there would exist a..." @MartinArgerami. How do I get this ?

Comment: $T$ unbounded means that for every $c>0$ there exists $x$ with $\|Tx\|>c\|x\|$.  If you divide by $\|x\|$ you see that this is equivalent to the existence of $x$ with $\|x\|=1$ and $\|Tx\|>c$. So you can find $y_n$ with $\|y_n\|=1$ and $\|Ty_n\|>n^2$.  Now take $x_n=y_n/n$.

Answer (score 4):

The reverse implication is a simple consequence of the closed-graph theorem: Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $x_n\to x$ and $Tx_n\to y$. We need to show $Tx=y$. Since every strongly convergent sequence is weakly convergent, it follows $x_n\rightharpoonup x$, and by the assumption $Tx_n \rightharpoonup Tx$. Since weak limits are unique, $Tx=y$, the graph of $T$ is closed, and $T$ is continuous.

Comment: what do you mean by weak limits?

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing down $||Tx_n-Tx||=||T(x_n-x)||$ by linearity, try using the definition of boundedness of the operator $T$ to obtain an inequality involving $||x_n-x||$. Now you want to use that $x_n\rightarrow x$, think about what value of $\epsilon$ you want to use in the definition of convergence to show that $Tx_n\rightarrow T x$.

Comment: -1: This makes no sense. It's not related to weak convergence, does not deal with the reverse implication (which is the non-trivial one), nor is  related to the fact that $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: The person referenced an answer in which they were trying to prove the forwards direction, so I was trying to clarify how one would approach that. But thanks for clarifying the backwards direction.